# Can a method in the class receive the same class as parameter?

Tags: c#, class

I have a class

```
public class Position
{
    public double X_long { get; set; }
    public double Y_lat { get; set; }
}
```

And I have a separated function to send the Position to my webservice.

```
private void PositionSaveWeb(Position sp)
{
    var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest
                           .Create("http://myserver.com/ApiTest/api/Position");
    httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
    httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 
            | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 
            | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;

    using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
    {
        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(sp);
        streamWriter.Write(json);
        streamWriter.Flush();
        streamWriter.Close();
    }

    string result = TryWebRequest(httpWebRequest);
}
```

I wonder can/should I add that method to the class or is ok like is now:

```
public class Position
{
    public double X_long { get; set; }
    public double Y_lat { get; set; }

    public void Save (Position sp) {
    }
}
```

The problems I have here are:

- In javascript when you declare a class you have `this`. So I could call `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this);` but here don't know how I can serialize the object. Unless I use the public variables to create a new Position Object inside the method. But that feel weird using the thing you are creating to create something. I don't want create an infinitive recursive loop or something.
- Now the class also include a method, would this method also be serialized.

So should `Save` be a method of the Class, and if so how I add it?

Comment: Why do you need to give the method the parameter? If you have a `Position` object, why not call its `Save` method?

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen That is the question. `JsonConvert.SerializeObject()` need the object. As I explain in javascript you use `this` to self reference inside the class in C# dont know what to use.

Comment: C# has `this` as well.

Comment: Methods don't get serialized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To directly answer the title question, a class can have a method with a parameter if its own type, and that's normal.

```
public class Values
{
    public int X { get; set; }
    public int Y { get; set; }

    public void Add(Values other)
    {
        X += other.X;
        Y += other.Y;
    }
}
```

Methods don't get serialized, so the class would be serialized the same with or without that method.

---

I definitely wouldn't put a `PositionSaveWeb` method in your `Position` class. The purpose of your `Position` class is to represent a position. There are a million things you can do with that class - serialize it, post it in an `HttpRequest`, send it in an email, etc. But those things aren't the responsibility of that class.

It's called the Single Responsibility Principle. A class has one purpose, and only one reason to change. So if you determine that a `Position` has three points, you might change that class. But you wouldn't want to change that class because now you want to send it via some different method.

So in this case I'd recommend that `PositionSaveWeb` should be its own class.

Answer (score 1):

You can absolutely add the `Save` method to your class. However, since you are not using `Position` object itself, `Save` method should be `static`:

```
public static void Save (Position sp) {
    ...
}
```

> that feel weird using the thing you are creating to create something

Using `static` solves this problem

> the class also include a method, would this method also be serialized.

In C# methods are not objects (although there are objects that describe methods, namely, `MethodInfo`) Hence, methods don't get serialized.

Comment: Sorry I think I explain it wrong. But thanks for the static explanation that also was good to know. The idea is add the method to the class and just use `sp.Save()` so doesn't need  pass the parameter. But I need the object to call `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(sp);`

Answer (score 1):

[JSON](https://www.json.org/) doesn't contain methods, so any method you add to Position will not be included.

You can use `this` in C# as well, like in JavaScript, in this case. While they mean a slightly different thing, you can use it to reference the current object.

```
class Test {
    public void test() {
        Console.WriteLine(this);
    }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Test test = new Test();
        test.test();
    }
}
```

Will output `Test` ([Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ZrZKiT))

### Note

That said I still don't recommend adding the Save method to the Position itself, because you are most probably adding too many responsibilities, violating the [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)

If you leave the Position parameter on a method of Position, no one would be able to extend the class properly, breaking the [Open/closed principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle) as well.

If you make it static like @dasblinkenlight said, you are also breaking the [Dependency inversion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle)

JavaScript is a functional language, but C# is object oriented. While you can implement/force one on another (e.g. TypeScript), you might face other problems on the long run. You can always introduce new classes to break apart code that feels weird, which I would recommend on this case.